# port automatically changed to proxy port when applying a http proxy for ssh access to github

Tags: git, github, ssh, proxy

I setup a http proxy to access github.com via ssh.

```
git config --global http.proxy "http://the.proxy.com:46327"
git config --global https.proxy "http://the.proxy.com:46327"
```

But when pulling, the github.com:443 changed to github.com:46327 automatically. And it failed to work.

[the change http://lolofinil.qiniudn.com/git_proxy_prot_change.png](http://lolofinil.qiniudn.com/git_proxy_prot_change.png)

The proxy is a http/https proxy according to the service provider. I use it as Windows system proxy too, it works fine when exploring the internet.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that the proxy software is running and can be reached from your machine? I know that Git shows the proxy port in the error message if the proxy can't be reached for some reason. Make sure that the proxy can be reached on that port, check for typos, etc.